# FlexibleSearch using enum in WHERE clause

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working with Hybris and trying to query all the products that have an approval status of APPROVED within Java code. It should look like below, but I cannot get it to work in either HAC, or in Java code.

What is the correct way to do it?

```
SELECT {p:pk} FROM {Product as p join EnumerationValue as enum on enum.pk = p.approvalStatus } WHERE {enum:code[en]} = 'APPROVED'
```

---

Thank you everyone, here is the final answer that works, see comments in other replies for some more questions I have and hopefully some wonderfully wise replies:

```
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("SELECT {p:").append(ProductModel.PK).append("} ");
        stringBuilder.append("FROM {").append(ProductModel._TYPECODE).append(" as p join ")
                .append(ArticleApprovalStatus._TYPECODE).append(" as enum on {enum.pk} = {p.").append(ProductModel.APPROVALSTATUS).append("} join ")
                .append(CatalogVersionModel._TYPECODE).append(" as cv on {cv.pk} = {p.").append(ProductModel.CATALOGVERSION).append("} } ");
        stringBuilder.append("WHERE ( {enum:code} = ?approvalStatus1 or {enum:code} = ?approvalStatus2} and {cv:")
                .append(CatalogVersionModel.VERSION)
                .append("} = ?version");

        final String unapprovedString = ArticleApprovalStatus.UNAPPROVED.toString().toLowerCase();
        params.put("approvalStatus1", unapprovedString);
        params.put("approvalStatus2", ArticleApprovalStatus.UNAPPROVED.toString().toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the type of the enum. Also, the enum code is case-sensitive; it depends on what is defined in the items.xml.

```
SELECT * FROM {Product 
JOIN ArticleApprovalStatus ON {Product.approvalStatus} = {ArticleApprovalStatus.pk}}
WHERE {ArticleApprovalStatus.code} = 'approved'
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution.  One thing I missed originally was the fact you said it was case-sensitive.  As you can see from my final, working, solution, I am not a big fan of using hard coded strings, rather pull them from the correct code.  What I don't like is how I am converting the UNAPPROVED to lowercase.  Is there a better way to get the correct lower case value?

Comment: @Riley Use ArticleApprovalStatus.UNAPPROVED.getCode()  so that you will always get the correct code value. Also, if this answer helped you, please upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the attributes with {} like this:

```
SELECT {p:pk} FROM {Product as p join EnumerationValue as enum on {enum.pk} = {p.approvalStatus} } WHERE {enum:code[en]} = 'APPROVED'
```

Comment: Thank you, I have a question about the where clause.  I discovered the hard way that it is not 'APPROVED' but 'approved'.  Will using the language modifier on the enum resolve the case-ssensitive issue I ran into?

Comment: You can try to wrap both variables with lower() like this: lower({alias:property})